# Initialize Interface from Fragment implements Interface

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, interface, android-webview

I 've an `Activity`(**MainActivity.java**) , a `Fragment`(**HomeFragment.java**) inside `Activity`(**MainActivity.java**) and an `interface`(**WebViewListener**). My `Fragment` implements `interface` and has a `WebView` inside it.

My Interface is:

**WebViewListener**

```
public interface WebViewListener {
    public void interactWithWebView();
}
```

My Fragment is:

**HomeFragment.java**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements WebViewListener {
  private WebView webView;

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
      webView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
      ...
      webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/dropdown.html");
      return v;
  }


  @Override
  public void interactWithWebView() {
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.in/");
  }

}
```

In My `Activity` I have a `Button`, on click of that `Button` I intialize interface and call interface method. (In interface method I load google url in `WebView`).

My Activity is:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn= (Button ) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // Intialize interface and call interface method...
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Here is my Question:**

In MainActivity on `Button` click if I intialize `WebViewListener` interface and call its method like below

```
WebViewListener webViewListener=new HomeFragment();
webViewListener.interactWithWebView();
```

`WebView` gives `NullPointerException` in `interactWithWebView()` method.

and if I intialize WebViewListener interface and call its method like this:

```
WebViewListener webViewListener = (WebViewListener) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentName);
webViewListener.interactWithWebView();
```

`WebView` load google url pretty much fine in `interactWithWebView()` method. What is the reason behind it?

Comment: @DownVoter Please tell the reason of downvote.

Comment: Please  read the question carefully. I dont think there is any need of logcat . I just ask the difference. @SuhasB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in when you create a new instance of your fragment and use it as `WebViewListener` , you will face `NullPointerException` because in `interactWithWebView` method, your `webView` object is null because no view is inflated and there is no webView, but when you use `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentName);` you are referencing a previously defined fragment that inflated its view and has a valid webView object and you have no problem using it.